# Symfony CreateForm function runs out of memory

Tags: php, apache, symfony, memory

I'm working on a 2.8 symfony project and I can't solve a problem I've been dealing with for a few weeks.

Every form I'm trying to create gets me a "Allowed memory size exhausted" error. This should be a configuration problem because my project is working on dev and prod environments, and on other computers. It's just not working on mine.

> Error exemple : OutOfMemoryException in BundleEntryReader.php line
>   134:
>
> Error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 134217736 bytes)

I'm working on Ubuntu. I tried remove and re-install both apache and php (7.1), but no success. I also tried to allow more memory and execution time, but my scripts keep running for dozens of minutes.

```php
$projectForm = $this->createForm(
     new ProjectType($choices, $user->getCompany()),
     $project,
     ['action' => $this->generateUrl('company_project_create',['projectId' => $project->getId() ])]
);
```

I'd like to be able to generate a form. the problem is in the form generation. In every script I use, evrything is ok until the "$this->createForm()" function. Let's says that this application runs on computers with less ram.

/*****EDIT*****/

I found that the problem came from two types in my ProjectType : user and address :

```php
$builder            
     ->add('user', UserType::class, [
          'label' => 'customer.user.label',
     ])
     ->add('address', ProjectAddressType::class, [
          'label' => 'customer.project.address.label',
     ])
```

Here is for example where my userType has problem :

```php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
     parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
     $builder
          ->add('photo', HiddenType::class, ['required'    => false])
          ->add('isSendDailyMail', CheckboxType::class, [
              'label'    => false,
              'required' => false,
     ]);
}
```

Comment: Show code for ProjectType. How many elements in $choices?

Comment: 5 elements, not too big. But the problem also shows on other forms much simple.

Comment: do you have any `var_dump` or `print_r` or `var_export` or similar in your code? maybe xdebug installed? because if any of those try to recursively turn an object into a string it could very easily allocate *all* memory ... because there actually IS recursion. (proxy objects / entities have links to entity manager and vice-versa)

Comment: Non, there is no var_dump, dump or something like this. xDebug is not installed. No data is printed.

Comment: I remember something similar happening, when the php installation was corrupted (1 bit flip). can you check on a different machine and/or maybe reinstall php?

Comment: You're the man Jalumi !!!!! You were right, something was wrong in my php. I reinstalled php7.1 and evrything is ok now. Thank you a lot for your help.